# Exchange Web Service (EWS) C# obtener emails de una carpeta expecífica

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy conectándome al servicio de Exchange para obtener los emails, pero no veo cómo hacerlo de una carpeta creada por mí en la cuenta.

Para los emails del Inbox no hay problema:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, ...);
```

Pero no consigo reemplazar el `WellKnownFolderName.Inbox` por el nombre de mi carpeta.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. ¿Este código te da algún error? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta agregando mas información. _qué problemas tienes con este código, descripción de errores, qué esperas obtener, etc_

Answer (score 1):

Intenta algo como los siguiente, donde primero buscamos el `Folder` y luego buscamos los `Ítems` directamente desde el `Folder` encontrado:

```
// Se define la variable del servicio
var services = ..... 

// Establecemos el nombre de la carpeta que se desea buscar
String folderSearchName = "Nombre de la carpeta que se desea encontrar";

// Establecemos los criterios de busqueda
FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(1);
fvFolderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;
SearchFilter fsFolderSearch = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, folderSearchName);
FolderId searchRoot = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root);

// Realizamos la busqueda de la carpeta
FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = service.FindFolders(searchRoot, fsFolderSearch, fvFolderView);

// Si la busqueda de la carpeta fue exitosa, entonces buscamos los items
if (folderSearchResults.Folders.Count == 1) 
{
    var results = folderSearchResults.Folders[0].FindItems(.....);
}
```

Comment: Va muy bien. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @JosebaRodríguez, me alegra que te haya servido!!!. No olvides marcar las respuesta como correcta, para que otras personas puedan encontrar fácilmente este problema y su solución.